# Не могу получить количество друзей VK API

Tags: php, веб-программирование, vkontakte-api

```
                $user_id = ***;
            $request_params = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'fields' => 'counters',
                    'v' => '5.60'
            );
            $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
            $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'. $get_params));
            //echo ($result[0])
            //echo ($result -> response[0] -> counters[0] -> friends);
            print_r($result);
            echo '<br><br><br>';
            print_r($result -> response[0] -> counters -> friends);
```

Получаю вот такой ответ

> stdClass Object ( [response] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => ***[first_name] => Олег [last_name] => Овчаренко [counters] => stdClass Object ( [albums] => 0 [videos] => 2 [audios] => 0 [notes] => 0 [photos] => 1 [followers] => 134 ) [hidden] => 1 ) ) )

Нет поля **friends** но по документации вконтакте это поле должно быть 
чит.counter [документация вк](https://vk.com/dev/fields)

Comment: В той же документации: **counters** - количество различных объектов у пользователя. Поле возвращается только в методе users.get при запросе информации об одном пользователе, с передачей **access_token**. Вы передаете access_token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться функцией

```
public function get_friends($u_id) {
     $friends = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id='.$u_id);
     $friends = json_decode($friends);

     if(!isset($friends->error)){
         return $friends;
     }else{
         return '';
     }         
}
```

Comment: return count($friends -> response);